Prove $X=Y$ almost surely $\implies E[X] = E[Y]$
I'm not entirely sure how we can go from probability to expectation. Here's what I have so far:

Assume $X=Y$ almost surely. By definition, $P(X=Y)=1 \implies P(X-Y=0)=1$;
Let $Z=X-Y$, then $P(Z=0)=1$;
(some intermediate step)
$E(Z) = 0 \implies E[X] = E[Y]$.


Perhaps $\operatorname{E} [Z] = \int\limits_\Omega Z,d\operatorname{P} = \int\limits_{{\omega \mid Z=0}} Z,d\operatorname{P} +\int\limits_{{\omega \mid Z\not =0}} Z,d\operatorname{P} = 0+0$ is the kind of thing you are thinking about, integrating $0$ over a set of measure $1$ to get $0$ and integrating something else over a set of measure $0$ to also get $0$.

For a rigorous proof (of this statement or statements like "integrating something over a set of measure 0 is 0"), you need to return to the primitive definition of measure-theoretic integral. A detailed proof can be found in Theorem 15.2 in Probability and Measure by Patrick Billingsley.

Nothing fancy is needed, because from basic definitions $$E[X]-E[Y] = E[X-Y] = 0(\Pr(X=Y))+\int_{X\ne Y}(X-Y)dP=0.$$

@whuber As I commented above, technically, the last equality in your comment deserves a separated proof.

@Zhanxiong Such a proof usually is one of the very first ones offered in any account of integration.  Surely the fact is emphasized in any introductory discussion of measure zero sets and what that means!

Since $\mathbb{P}(X=Y) = 1$ you can use the law of total expectation to get:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X-Y)
&= \mathbb{E}(X-Y|X=Y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=Y) + \mathbb{E}(X-Y|X \neq Y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) \\[6pt]
&= 0 \cdot 1 + \mathbb{E}(X-Y|X \neq Y) \cdot 0 \\[6pt]
&= 0 + 0 \\[6pt]
&= 0 . \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Thank you so much, this is really helpful!

As you outlined, with $Z = X - Y$, the goal is to show $E[Z] = 0$ under the condition $X = Y$ almost surely.
To this end, first note that $Z = 0$ almost surely implied that $Z^+ = 0$ almost surely and $Z^- = 0$ almost surely.
Then note that because $Z^+$ is non-negative, $Z^+ = 0$ almost surely requires $E[Z^+] = 0$ -- this is because by the definition of the integral,
\begin{align*}
E[Z^+] &= \int_\Omega Z^+dP = \sup_{\{A_i\} \text{ decomposes } \Omega}\sum_i\left[\inf_{\omega \in A_i}Z^+(\omega)\right]P(A_i) = 0,
\end{align*}
the last equality holds because if $A_i$ meets $\{Z^+ = 0\}$, then the infimum is $0$; otherwise, $P(A_i) = 0$. Hence each sum in the above expression is $0$. Similarly $E[Z^-] = 0$.  Therefore, $E[Z] = E[Z^+] - E[Z^-] = 0$.
